# Queued transactions in Java EntityManager

Tags: java, cassandra

My Java code:

```
private EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("cassandra_pu");
private EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
while(condition){
em.merge(objects[i]);
}
```

It can be executed normally without any exception but there is no update in the database table; I thinking that is that because all transactions are queued, if it was, is there anyway to commit the transaction immediately?

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? How is it configured?

Comment: actually i'm using no sql db cassandra via kundera

Comment: Is it supporting transactions?

Answer (score 0):

cassandra does not support transactions so unless you have a co-ordinating server like zookeeper you won'at have transactions.  PlayOrm was specifically not JPA compliant as noSQL can do sooo much more like with the @NoSqlEmbedded tag on a List of String or List of LocalDate.  These are things JPA for an RDBMS can't support as RDBMS does not have wide rows.  Anyways, PlayOrm is another option but again, doesn't do transactions but is more geared to supporting many noSQL patterns in use today that are not doable in JPA.

In both PlayOrm and JPA, you DO NEED to call flush though.  **Are you missing a call to flush?**

oh, and I should note PlayOrm is very very similar to JPA in look and feel but with more noSQL specific features(plus it does joins as well when needed)